# pcap inject on tap/tun device

Tags: pcap, inject, network-interface

I am trying to have two tap interface on one machine and a simulated link between them (using ns3 tapbridge). Suppose I have tap0 and tap1. 
When sending on tap0, I can see my frame on wireshark but nothing on tap1. 
My questions: Why am I not able to see my frames on the other tap device even if I'm on promiscuous mode? Is it even possible to do raw sockets on a tap device ?